# Sending encrypted mail using PHP

Tags: php, email, encryption

Currently I am sending non encrypted mails. Now I want to send encrypted mails, for this I am referred to `openssl_pkcs7_encrypt()`.

I didn't understand the part regarding the public key certificate.

If someone knows about this, please could you explain how I can generate this public key certificate or any alternate solution to send encrypted mails.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL has always eluded my proper understanding so I can not explain this easily for you. But I do know you need to have already generated an SSL key, CSR, self-signed certificates, and then the .pem file which you need.

You may want to follow this link for a brief tutorial:

[Creating SSL keys, CSRs, self-signed certificates, and .pem files.](http://grahamc.com/blog/openssl-madness-how-to-create-keys-certificate-signing-requests-authorities-and-pem-files/)

Depending on what you may have already done, what you may need may simply be just this:

```
`cat domain.tld.key domain.tld.crt > domain.tld.pem`
```

Where `domain.tld.key` and `domain.tld.crt` are the path to the generated files using the tutorial provided above. `domain.tld.pem` will be the path to the file to be created, which is the public key you need for `openssl_pkcs7_encrypt()`.

I hope this helps.